# Doctrine Query Builder: FIND_IN_SET doesn't work

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `Customer` with a `simple_array` field "`myNumbers`" which values for example are "`12233,45454,99`" in my DB.
So I want to search for this entity, which has the number 99 in it.
I tried it with the query builder an a nativeQuery, but I always get an error that says, `":Customer not found in params array")`

```
$this->entityManager()->createNativeQuery("SELECT c, FIND_IN_SET(c.myNumbers, :searchNumber) FROM MyBundle:Customer", new ResultSetMapping())->setParameter('searchNumber', $number)->getResult();
```

Alraedy tried it with the real table name "Customer":

```
 $this->entityManager()->createNativeQuery("SELECT c, FIND_IN_SET(c.myNumbers, :searchNumber) FROM Customer c", new ResultSetMapping())->setParameter('searchNumber', $number)->getResult();
```

then the error is:

```
Column not foun: 1054 Unkown column "c" in field list
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I don't think the error is with the find_in_set. What is `MyBundle:Customer`? If that's a table name, then you must enclose it by backticks. Also, if you want to search for a record matching certain criteria, then the criteria must be in the where clause, as opposed to the select list.

Comment: @Shadow see my edit please

Comment: You must use an existing column name from the table. `c` is the alias for the table, not a column name. `*` stands for all columns. Is it really so hard to interpret the 2nd error message?

Comment: @Shadow: So i thought i get the whole entity by saying, "c". sorry andy thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a native query, your `FROM` clause must specify a table name not an entity.  As it is, when Doctrine stumbles upon `MyBundle:Customer`, it thinks that `:Customer` is a named parameter, thus the error you get since you did not set any parameter with that name afterwards.

Simply replace `MyBundle:Customer` by the name of the corresponding table to solve the problem. You can use `$entityManager->getClassMetadata('MyBundle:Customer')->getTableName()` to retrieve the table name of your entity.

---

**Edit:** If you are having trouble building your query, you should really have a look at the Doctrine documentation related to native queries. Especially the section about the [`ResultSetMappingBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder). The easiest way to correctly select the fields you want is to use that tool to generate the select clause for you and correctly map the result set to hydrate your `Customer` entity afterwards.

Here is a sample of code modified to fit your example:

```php
$em = $this->entityManager();
$tableName = $em->getClassMetadata('MyBundle:Customer')->getTableName();
$tableAlias = 'c';

$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('MyBundle:Customer', $tableAlias);

$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT ' . $rsm->generateSelectClause([$tableAlias => $tableAlias]) . ' 
    FROM ' . $tableName . ' ' . $tableAlias . '
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.myNumbers, :searchNumber)
', $rsm);

$query->getResult();
```

Comment: So the tableName is "Customer" and then the error is: Column not foun: 1054 Unkown column "c" in field list

Comment: @Zwen2012  You need to write `FROM Customer c` to specify an alias for your table

Comment: @Zwen2012 You should really use `ResultSetMappingBuilder` here. I updated my post to include some code to show you how you could use it.